# R: grouping error in survdiff function

Tags: r, error-handling, survival-analysis

I constructed the following dataframe for the purposes of this question:

```
head(exprs, 21)

   sample expr              ID X_OS
1     BIX high TCGA_DM_A28E_01   26
2     BIX high TCGA_AY_6197_01   88
3     BIX high TCGA_HB_KH8H_01  553
4     BIX  low TCGA_K4_6303_01  256
5     BIX  low TCGA_F4_6703_01  491
6     BIX  low TCGA_Y7_PIK2_01  177
7     BIX  low TCGA_A6_5657_01  732
8     HEF high TCGA_DM_A28E_01   26
9     HEF high TCGA_AY_6197_01   88
10    HEF high TCGA_F4_6703_01  491
11    HEF high TCGA_HB_KH8H_01  553
12    HEF  low TCGA_K4_6303_01  256
13    HEF  low TCGA_Y7_PIK2_01  177
14    HEF  low TCGA_A6_5657_01  732
15    TUR high TCGA_DM_A28E_01   26
16    TUR high TCGA_F4_6703_01  491
17    TUR high TCGA_Y7_PIK2_01  177
18    TUR  low TCGA_K4_6303_01  256
19    TUR  low TCGA_AY_6197_01   88
20    TUR  low TCGA_HB_KH8H_01  553
21    TUR  low TCGA_A6_5657_01  732
```

I wish to run a log rank test that compares survival curves for high and low `expr` groups for each `sample`:

```
expfun = function(x) {
  survdiff( Surv( X_OS, rep(1,nrow(x)) ) ~ expr, data=x)
}
dfx <- lapply(split(exprs[c("expr", "X_OS")], exprs$sample), expfun)
```

So, it takes a single `sample`, compares the two `expr` group survival curves from the column `X_OS`, and stores the log rank test results. The problem is that I run into the following error (when using the actual data, not the sample data above. However the format is exactly the same):

```
Error in survdiff.fit(y, groups, strata.keep, rho) : 
  There is only 1 group
Called from: survdiff.fit(y, groups, strata.keep, rho)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to remedy this situation?

Comment: Check if one of your sample levels is all highs or lows

Comment: @rawr I have over 20,000 samples levels, so I cannot parse through them easily. Is there a way to produce output even if there is only one group in a given sample level (i.e., I need there to be some kind of output for each of my samples, otherwise the next stage of my code will not work).

Comment: wrap it in try: `try(survdiff(...))` you will still get the error but the code will keep running... Oh that's not what you were asking, is it? I don't think you can just make it work, but you can keep the loop running, there won't be any output for that one, just the error message

Comment: @rawr is there any way to just put out "NA" for those samples that have one group only?

Comment: in that case, you can use `tryCatch` for more thorough error handling. try, `tryCatch(survdiff(...), error = function(e) return(NA))` which will return NA if an error is encountered rather than printing the error message